# retrieve date in controller from ng-repeat angularsJS (ionic)

Tags: angularjs, json

I retrieve data(a date) from a json and i used ng-repeat to diplay them but i want to use momentjs to set a new format of my date. My issue is that i don t know how to get the value from "item.date" in my controller to set my format. here is my code :

controller :

```
.controller('RegistreCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams,factotransaction) {
    console.log("coucou");
    var mytoken = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    factotransaction.send(mytoken).then(function(conf){
    console.log(conf);
            $scope.datab = conf.data;

    })

})
```

view :

```
<ion-view view-title="Registre">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Registre</h1>
    <ul class="list" ng-repeat="item in datab track by $index">

      <li class="item" ng-repeat="mytitle in item.assignation">
        {{item.date}}

          {{mytitle.category}}{{mytitle.amount}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

json : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of possibilities, two of which are:

You can use a directive to handle your `item`, where you can do with your data whatever you want. Something like

```
<item data="item" ng-repeat="item in datab track by $index"></item>
```

and

```
.directive('item', function(){
    controller: function($scope){
        // do stuff with $scope.item
    },
    scope: {
        item: '=data'
    }
});
```

You also can do your date stuff with a filter, specially if you want to only display the date in a certain way:

```
{{item.date | myDate}}
```

and

```
.filter('myDate', function(){
    return function(date){
        // do stuff with the date
        return formattedDate;
    }
});
```

Comment: Great explanation thanks a lot it was very helpfull :)